# What is the below architecture for?

Tags: c#, class, interface

In the below code, `MYClassB` inherits from both `MYClassA` and `IMyinterface`. But `MYClassA` already ingerits from `IMyinterface`.

1. Does it have any differece to use like `MYClassB : MYClassA` without `IMyinterface`?
2. If 1. has some differences please explain to me. And is there any reason to use this kind of confused classes in the real world?

   ```
   interface IMyinterface
   {
       void myfunc();
   }

   abstract class MyClassA : IMyinterface
   {
       public virtual void myfunc() 
       {
           Console.WriteLine("myfunc in MYClassA");
       }
   }

   class MYClassB : MyClassA, IMyinterface
   {
       public override void myfunc()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("myfunc in MYClassB");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The common name for this pattern is "bug".

Comment: This won't compile, because an abstract method can't have a body. 
Edit: And abstract can't be private

Comment: In addition, a member (here method) which is not `public` cannot implicitly implement an interface, so neither `class` has a method to satisfy the interface.

Comment: And a private method can't be abstract either.

Comment: I think you meant to say "`MYClassB` inherits from `MyClassA`...", not from `MYClassB`. I'd edit, but the edit is too minor for me to propose it.

Comment: Sorry I fixed the compile errors in my codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-declaring that the type implements implements the interface doesn't change anything *in the specific example that you showed*, but it *can* have an effect in other situations.

Specifically, re-declaring that the type implements the interface re-binds the methods implementing the interface.  Now, in your example this is irrelivant because, since `myfunc` is virtual and overridden, the same method body is executed *even if the method in `MYClassB` isn't re-bound to be the method implementing the interface*.  But consider this example:

```
interface IMyinterface
{
    void myfunc();
}

abstract class MyClassA : IMyinterface
{
    public void myfunc()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("myfunc in MYClassA");
    }
}

class MYClassB : MyClassA, IMyinterface
{
    public new void myfunc()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("myfunc in MYClassB");
    }
}
```

With a usage like so:

```
IMyinterface instance = new MYClassB();
instance.myfunc();
```

Here, the output is `MYClassB`, because `myfunc` is re-bound as the implementation of the interface to be the implementation in `MyClassB`.  But if you change the declaration of `MYClassB` to : `class MYClassB : MyClassA`, suddenly the output of the code is the `MYClassA` implementation, because the implementation of the interface is never re-bound from pointing to `MYClassA`'s implementation.

Additionally, if the deriving class would like to provide an explicit interface implementation it needs to explicitly re-declare that it is implementing the interface.

Comment: Just to come up with yet another example, try to compile this: `class ReImpl1 : IDisposable
  {
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("1");
    }
  }
  class ReImpl2 : ReImpl1
  {
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("2");
    }
  }` It gives a compile-time error. You must mention the interface again in the interface list in the declaration of the deriving class `ReImpl2` to make this legal. After that, it works as expected/intended.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Added a note to the answer to cover that case.

Comment: for Servy and @JeppeStigNielsen - This makes no sense.  You say "change the declaration of MYClassB to" and then you have the same thing you have in the code.  And I don't think you actually ran this, because I just have ran every permutation of the code, with and without abstract, with and without virtual, and with and without the interface specified on B.  Every time the output is the same.

Comment: @Gilchrist You're right, I thought I specified the original snippet as re-implementing the interface, but I didn't; I've edited the snippet.  Changing the snippet to re-implement the interface or not does indeed change the output of the program.

Comment: And I ran your code with the two different implementations and it does produce two DIFFERENT results.  Yet, grandpa's code does not.  I think you are running into problems using IDisposable.  The only thing I can think is that as a System interface, the compiler may be doing something different with it, even though its source code has no significant differences (that I can tell) from what grandpa had in his code.

Comment: I remember reading, from MS, that adding IDisposable to an existing class will break your code and that if you have to do it, you have to wrap the object in a safe handle.  In any case, using IDisposable to test something like this is not a good choice, far better to actually use the OP's code.

Comment: @Gilchrist I have explained to you, on several occasions, *exactly* why my example differs from the OP's.  The OP's method is virtual, and as a result, even though the interface maps to a different method, mapping the base method results in the base method deferring to the derived method (because that's how virtual methods work).  In order to observe the change in the interface's mapping, the method needs to not be virtual and overridden.  Nothing about the use of `IDisposable` is relevant here, not that I'm even using it in my examples.  Nothing about it is different or special.

Comment: @Servy - sorry about your example, got confused with Jeppe's.  But in your example, what makes a difference is not the use of virtual.  What makes a difference is that when you instantiate classB, you use the interface in the declaration.  Instantiate it as  MYClassB instance = new MYClassB(); and then try it with and without the Interface specification in the class definition, and you get the same results.

Comment: @Gilchrist Yes.  I specifically mentioned every single one of those points in my answer.  I've mentioned both in my answer, and in like 4 comments now that the method needs to not be virtual to observe the change, and of course the entire purpose of this whole process is determining what the interface binds the method to, which is only relevant when calling through the interface (as I specifically showed in my example).

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no difference functionally. By inheriting from MyClassA, your MyClassB object implicitly complies to your IMyInterface. Defining it the way you have is explicit and would show anyone browsing your code right away that it implements the interface but that is all. You gain nothing else by declaring the interface implementation on the MyClassB definition.
2. A real world example could be that you have a contract that must be implemented (IMyInterface) but a lot of the implementations that you have do very similar operations to perform the work with small deviations. In this case you would implement from a [template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) as defined in MyClassA.

Comment: However, see [Interface re-implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664594.aspx). Not relevant for an `override`, though.

Comment: ood point. And one that I've forgotten about since I've used it so infrequently